# Correct use of operators within mutate() and rowwise()

Tags: r

I am working on a dataset containing data from a survey that I have conducted. The survey relates to mental health and high scores in some domains indicate poor mental health and others 'good' mental health. Therefore using mutate() and rowwise() I am now trying to calculate domain scores using logical operators *within* mutate. I have tried the following small data to check, and looks ok, but it feels like a sketchy solution, any thoughts on how to improve, or is this ok?

My data is similar do this:

```
#Create fake data where x, y and z are facet scores. 
df <- tibble(x = 1:2, y = 3:4, z = 5:6)

#Calculate domain score (m) where high score on y is negative.
df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(m = mean(c(x, 3-y, z)))
```

Note: In my "real" dataframe I subtract mean from the number of facets within the domain, used 3 to check how R handles the subtraction.

First time asking a question, so hope my examples etcetera are ok..

Thanks in advance
//Ems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change the columns that need to be changed and then use `rowMeans` which would be much faster than using `rowwise` and `mean`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(y = 3  - y) %>% mutate(m = rowMeans(.))
```

Comment: Thanks! That seems like a much quicker way and cleaner way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

We could use `base R`

```
df$y <- 3 - df$y
df$m <- rowMeans(df)
```